# How to type check if object keys conform a conditional recursive template type?

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, class-names

The question is easy to understand with an example. I'd want to achieve a strictly type guarded wrapper for https://npmjs.com/package/classnames, to type check the Tailwind class names that our app uses.

So far the closest solution is this example:

```js
// Credits to https://dev.to/virtualkirill/make-your-css-safer-by-type-checking-tailwind-css-classes-2l14
type Colors = "red" | "purple" | "blue" | "green";
type Luminance = 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900;
type BgColor = `bg-${Colors}-${Luminance}`;
type Layout = "block" | "w-1" | "h-1";
type TailwindClass = BgColor | Layout;

type ValidTailwindClassSeparatedBySpace<S> = S extends `${infer Class} ${infer Rest}`
  ? Class extends TailwindClass
    ? `${Class} ${ValidTailwindClassSeparatedBySpace<Rest>}`
    : never
  : S extends `${infer Class}`
  ? Class extends TailwindClass
    ? S
    : never
  : never;

type ValidTailwind<T> = T extends ValidTailwindClassSeparatedBySpace<T> ? T : never;
type ClassNames<R> = keyof R extends ValidTailwind<keyof R> ? R : never;

function classNamesWrapper<R>(obj: ClassNames<R>): string {
  // All arguments would be passed to npmjs.com/package/classnames
  // For the example, just return empty string.
  return '';
}

classNamesWrapper({ 
  "bg-red-100": true, 
  "block w-1": true 
});

classNamesWrapper({ 
  "bad-class": false,  // only this key should be invalid
  "block h-1": true
});
```

The example code available here: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMBMEsAuBnUiD2oAWjEAdkAuEWaANwDoNgz5JEBXAQwBsBrO%20Fl4AWybbQAtAE90DSEIDGyZEORMAZtEkAjEUMQi8wqVmhSOAOwDmmplwDu8I7GmzpLJrOhyATCwCMAFgBQWnQh0FnRIVABeUAAiGFgo0AAfaLwJPBZoeKSo1RYGDMTokxhoIyiAbn9taFAAGQZeGyYjKWrIzwAGdoK3ToKAZl6k70HQAFYRgDYRgHYRgA4RgE5OioDqgCETcGDQ0EiAA1UzABIAb22QsIBfITO6hqMmlqv91arapjEGRD3onPRDJlopYhJ4gVEsKDypVAgAVCwsay2cBOWS-TYXXZJGqfcSICow6oANVY8Fg8KsNlgKOcyAAytA8ExIExEHB1iI6UyWgAeOkAPl%20dNA0AAHmzbKh9mcbMpIBBUcgrqAZUY5aAAEquRAvXygUAAfgVtJF4pKsFQFMRVJpsj1%20sNoGl50VyrOJJYZKtSOpioZTJZbNgHK5TF5WuQiH5uodoEIoCM5BU9vjwrFEotTtV6ttSv29qNudNGctCJ9uft%20qNdMrcYTScgKfrZBUBLWoA9XrLVJ5sMFkVhxfNqE75O7yL9jOZrPZnO50F7gqNg-jiZbkDegVzADkmLxXDyNf3QIIxIpNUPJR3SWPKbYeaf0Oej46NXW163fL5FAxmoh4OgRigFIiq7vuyAAOosngOiQIe-IABToKoABW8Y7nuB5HgAlPGkaQDYJigKc9ogKAACC3CgMyJj1CUKCgJY4gsLAoCqNUTIuKxGAJngvAocgFBSOgvDANybBMCY0DACBtKPOBpFgAAYrsiD6Kae5pNAAA0oAoQwkagDAjCQEB0C8HgWigPhhEUPaxkSEBADkTkVFcX6ybIYGuFBTAwSoCGnKA9rZGYsSgp0UTxogkB5LpIX-IYjFQtFsXVL4VzYQSnnIN5kHQbBgXBfq2RMHYOVRaAiisMgOn6mRgEsCIaBYPAqCntZWDMax7GgDYZA3glIRJZCYKpXkGVZUAA)

This works, but the error is not tied to the specific key of the object, but rather all of the object keys. TypeScript will highlight also `"block h-1"` to have the same error: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.`.

How could the typing be done so that TS would be able to detect that only the "bad-class" key is invalid Tailwind class string, but not highlight the "block h-1" as invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the specific issue you're seeing I'd change `ClassNames` to this:

```
type ClassNames<R> = { [K in keyof R]: K extends ValidTailwind<K> ? R[K] : never };
```

Instead of `ClassNames<R>` returning either `R` or `never`, it [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) each property name `K` in `R` to either `R[K]` (the property that was already there) or `never`.  Therefore the error should appear only on the offending properties:

```
classNamesWrapper({
  "bad-class": false,  // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'
  "block h-1": true // okay
});
```

(Please note that I haven't spent any time looking at the rest of the example code to see if it is reasonable; I've focused specifically on the question as asked.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=4#code/PTAEGECcFMBMEsAuBnUiD2oAWjEAdkAuEWaANwDoNgz5JEBXAQwBsBrO+Fl4AWybbQAtAE90DSEIDGyZEORMAZtEkAjEUMQi8wqVmhSOAOwDmmplwDu8I7GmzpLJrOhyATCwCMAFgBQWnQh0FnRIVABeUAAiGFgo0AAfaLwJPBZoeKSo1RYGDMTokxhoIyiAbn9taFAAGQZeGyYjKWrIzwAGdoK3ToKAZl6k70HQAFYRgDYRgHYRgA4RgE5OioDqgCETcGDQ0EiAA1UzABIAb22QsIBfITO6hqMmlqv91arapjEGRD3onPRDJlopYhJ4gVEsKDypVAgAVCwsay2cBOWS-TYXXZJGqfcSICow6oANVY8Fg8KsNlgKOcyAAytA8ExIExEHB1iI6UyWgAeOkAPl+dNA0AAHmzbKh9mcbMpIBBUcgrqAZUY5aAAEquRAvXygUAAfgVtJF4pKsFQFMRVJpsj1htA0vOiuVZxJLDJVqR1MVDKZLLZsA5XKYvK1yEQ-N1+sIoCM5BU9tjwrFEotjtV6ttSv29qN2dNactCO92bzoDpSbjCcgVfjZBUBLWoHdnpLVJ5sMFkVhhfNqFb5PbyN9jOZrPZnO50E7gqNvdj9cbhONsgAckxeK4eRru6BTqAANoAaVANlAgjEik1AF1Y6fU-2W6Sh5TbDzj3PNSeb6BFzXQCuAlFAYZpEHgdAjFAKRFQ3LdkAAdRZPAdEgHd+QACnQVQACtY2zODt13ABKWMI0gGwTH3e0QFAABBbhQGZEx6hKFBQEscQWFgUBVGqJkXB4jA4zwXgcOQCgpHQXhgG5NgmBMaBgBg2lHngmiwAAMV2RB9FNTc0mgAAaUAcIYCNQBgRhICg6BeDwLRQHIyiKHtKyJCggByTyKiuXxfBU9dN1cJCmBQlQMNOe1sjMWJQU6KJY0QSA8iM6L-kMDioSSlLoF8K5iIJQLkEIxDkNQyL0qYOxisS0BFFYZBjP1WiVEgUIAEINIAP16vq+tAHkhCEUBYXeTzVHQYJoCaTyz1QIx0B+Wl4BMR4cmqYTm08pdIE89KQkyyEwRyvJ8sKoA)